# What is the most efficient way to make a 3D animation of moving cylinder in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, geometry

For a cylinder (or a cylinder-like object) with height *h* and radius *r*, I have a numpy array **A** which specifies the cylinder's 6 degrees of motion in 3D space (translation along *x*, *y*, *z* axes & rotation about *x*, *y*, *z* axes) in time.

I would like to create animation for the cylinder using **A**, and to be able to save it as a video file.

The following code is where I got so far. 
Is there any way to achieve what my code already does in a faster, more efficient way?
Also, how can I add to or modify my code to save the animation as video file?

```
# My Animation Code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection


def RotZ(x):
    return np.array([[np.cos(x), -np.sin(x), 0, 0], [np.sin(x), np.cos(x), 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])


def RotY(x):
    return np.array([[np.cos(x), 0, np.sin(x), 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [-np.sin(x), 0, np.cos(x), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])


def RotX(x):
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, np.cos(x), -np.sin(x), 0], [0, np.sin(x), np.cos(x), 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]])


def Trans(x,y,z):
    return np.array([[1, 0, 0, x], [0, 1, 0, y], [0, 0, 1, z], [0, 0, 0, 1]])


# Translation and Rotation Matrix in 3D space
def Matrix_Transform(x, y, z, qx, qy, qz):
    return np.matmul(np.matmul(np.matmul(Trans(x,y,z), RotX(qx)), RotY(qy)), RotZ(qz)) 

# Translate and Rotate in 3D space
def Transform(Obj, Transform_Matrix):

    transformed_vertex = np.zeros((3,len(Obj.vertex)))  # array initialization

    for i in range(0, len(Obj.vertex)):
        arr = np.append(Obj.vertex[i],0)  
        vertex_rotated = np.matmul(Transform_Matrix, arr)
        vertex_rotated_translated = vertex_rotated + Transform_Matrix[:,3]
        transformed_vertex[:,i] = vertex_rotated_translated[:3]

    return transformed_vertex


class AniObj:
    def __init__(self, r, h):
        self.vertex = np.array([[r                   , 0                   , -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(2 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(2 *np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(4 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(4 *np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(6 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(6 *np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(8 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(8 *np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(10*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(10*np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(12*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(12*np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(14*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(14*np.pi/8), -h/2],
                                [r                   , 0                   ,  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(2 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(2 *np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(4 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(4 *np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(6 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(6 *np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(8 *np.pi/8), r*np.sin(8 *np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(10*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(10*np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(12*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(12*np.pi/8),  h/2],
                                [r*np.cos(14*np.pi/8), r*np.sin(14*np.pi/8),  h/2]])

# Position and Rotation in time
A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0.01599998, 0, -0.0006239, 0, 0.01136968, 0],
              [0.05403919, 0, 0.00676171, 0, 0.03658598, 0],
              [0.10514987, 0, 0.03305278, 0, 0.06318129, 0],
              [0.16226590, 0, 0.08316074, 0, 0.07898396, 0],
              [0.22450262, 0, 0.15264478, 0, 0.07800290, 0],
              [0.29704876, 0, 0.22760964, 0, 0.06264864, 0],
              [0.37834865, 0, 0.29329005, 0, 0.03757572, 0],
              [0.46285620, 0, 0.33771592, 0, 0.00815532, 0],
              [0.54269669, 0, 0.35392964, 0, -0.0215355, 0]])

# Parameters
radius = 5
height = 1

# Figure Setup
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# Animation
for i in range(0, len(A)):

    # Pause and clear window every iteration
    plt.pause(0.001)
    plt.cla()

    # Cylinder Setup
    CylinderObj = AniObj(radius, height)
    M = Matrix_Transform(A[i,0], A[i,1], A[i,2], A[i,3], A[i,4], A[i,5])
    CylinderObj.vertex = Transform(CylinderObj, M)
    Cylinder_vertices = list(zip(*(CylinderObj.vertex.tolist())))

    # Rendering in Poly3DCollection (list of list of triples) 
    # Top & Bottom
    Cylinder_Top    = [Cylinder_vertices[8:]]
    Cylinder_Bottom = [Cylinder_vertices[:8]]
    # Sides
    Cylinder_Side1  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[0 ], Cylinder_vertices[1 ], Cylinder_vertices[9 ], Cylinder_vertices[8 ])))]
    Cylinder_Side2  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[1 ], Cylinder_vertices[2 ], Cylinder_vertices[10], Cylinder_vertices[9 ])))]
    Cylinder_Side3  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[2 ], Cylinder_vertices[3 ], Cylinder_vertices[11], Cylinder_vertices[10])))]
    Cylinder_Side4  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[3 ], Cylinder_vertices[4 ], Cylinder_vertices[12], Cylinder_vertices[11])))]
    Cylinder_Side5  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[4 ], Cylinder_vertices[5 ], Cylinder_vertices[13], Cylinder_vertices[12])))]
    Cylinder_Side6  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[5 ], Cylinder_vertices[6 ], Cylinder_vertices[14], Cylinder_vertices[13])))]
    Cylinder_Side7  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[6 ], Cylinder_vertices[7 ], Cylinder_vertices[15], Cylinder_vertices[14])))]
    Cylinder_Side8  = [list(zip(*zip(Cylinder_vertices[7 ], Cylinder_vertices[0 ], Cylinder_vertices[8 ], Cylinder_vertices[15])))]

    # Plot Cylinder on Axis 
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Bottom, alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Top   , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side1 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='teal'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side2 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side3 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='teal'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side4 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side5 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='teal'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side6 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side7 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='teal'), zs='z')
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(Cylinder_Side8 , alpha=0.5,  linewidths=1, facecolors='darkcyan'), zs='z')

    # Set Window
    ax.set_xlim((-5, 5))
    ax.set_ylim((-5, 5))
    ax.set_zlim((-5, 5))


    # Show figure
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code is not displaying a moving cylinder at this moment

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I think it does, when using `plt.ion()`, which the OP is probably doing under the hood.

Comment: you are right, it does, thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest .

Comment: @AndrewChey I think such a question is better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), so just some hints: (1) Don't use interactive mode, but rather a `FuncAnimation`, (2) Don't clear the axes in each step, but rather only remove the artist(s), or even only update the vertices of the collection(s). (3) In principle you can create one single PolyCollection to host *all* of your "Cylinder". Of course asking a well scoped question on any single aspect mentionned here with a reasonable attempt would again be suitable for SO.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I see. Thank you for the suggestion!